# Bootstrap 'form-group has-error' not working with php codes

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

Inputs don't turn red and does not print the error messages when I'm submitting empty fields. How can I show the error messages and make the input boxes turn red when I'm sending empty fields with this code.

```
<?php 

  if ( !empty($_POST)) {
    require 'db.php';
    // validation errors
    $fnameError     = null;
    $lnameError     = null;
    $ageError       = null;
    $genderError    = null;

    // post values
    $fname  = $_POST['fname'];
    $lname  = $_POST['lname'];
    $age    = $_POST['age'];
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];

    // validate input
    $valid = true;
    if(empty($fname)) {
      $fnameError = 'Please enter First Name';
      $valid = false;
    }

    if(empty($lname)) {
      $lnameError = 'Please enter Last Name';
      $valid = false;
    }

    if(empty($age)) {
      $ageError = 'Please enter Age';
      $valid = false;
    }

    if(empty($gender)) {
      $genderError = 'Please select Gender';
      $valid = false;
    }

    // insert data
    if ($valid) {
      $PDO->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
      $sql = "INSERT INTO users (fname,lname,age,gender) values(?, ?, ?, ?)";
      $stmt = $PDO->prepare($sql);
      $stmt->execute(array($fname,$lname,$age,$gender));
      $PDO = null;
      header("Location: index.php");
    }
  }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link   href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="row">
        <h3>Create a User</h3>
      </div>

      <form method="POST" action="create.php">
        <div class="form-group <?php echo !empty($fnameError)?'has-error':'';?>">
          <label for="inputFName">First Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" id="inputFName" value="<?php echo isset($fname)?$fname:'';?>" name="fname" placeholder="First Name">
          <span class="help-block"><?php echo isset($fnameError)?$fnameError:'';?></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group <?php echo !empty($lnameError)?'has-error':'';?>">
          <label for="inputLName">Last Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" required="required" id="inputLName" value="<?php echo isset($lname)?$lname:'';?>" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name">
          <span class="help-block"><?php echo isset($lnameError)?$lnameError:'';?></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group <?php echo !empty($ageError)?'has-error':'';?>">
          <label for="inputAge">Age</label>
          <input type="number" required="required" class="form-control" id="inputAge" value="<?php echo isset($age)?$age:'';?>" name="age" placeholder="Age">
          <span class="help-block"><?php echo isset($ageError)?$ageError:'';?></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group <?php echo !empty($genderError)?'has-error':'';?>">
          <label for="inputGender">Gender</label>
          <select class="form-control" required="required" id="inputGender" name="gender" >
            <option></option>
            <option value="male" <?php echo isset($gender)?'selected':'';?>>Male</option>
            <option value="female" <?php echo isset($gender)?'selected':'';?>>Female</option>
          </select>
          <span class="help-block"><?php echo isset($genderError)?$genderError:'';?></span>

        </div>

        <div class="form-actions">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Create</button>
          <a class="btn btn btn-default" href="index.php">Back</a>
        </div>
      </form>

    </div> <!-- /row -->
  </div> <!-- /container -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: help me pls im stucked

Comment: Can you pastebin this together with the script and style includes?

Comment: these are the codes sir kindly please check thank you https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B76wr1kvOEudck42X1ZTODVMbjg/view?usp=sharing  i just want to trigger that "form-group has-error" and the "help-block"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

#### Note:

- If a user submits the form with empty fields except for gender, it will return true and will go to your insert statement. It will overwrite the value of your `$valid` variable in every `if()` statement.

You can try this instead for assigning value on your `$valid` variable:

```
if(empty($fname) || empty($lname) || empty($age) || empty($gender)){
  $valid = "false";
}
else {
  $valid = "true";
}
```

- Your form will return false also because of your `required = "required"` attribute on your input fields, so the form won't submit and you won't be able to see the result of your conditions.

#### Additional note:

- You can also use javascript to achieve what you want without submitting the form

If you want a sample of javascript, I can give you an example.

First, we want to assign a unique `id` attribute for your `div`s, `input fields` and `<span>`. And we should hide first the error message inside your `<span>`

Here is an example of your First Name field:

```
<div class="form-group" id="firstnamediv">
  <label for="inputFName">First Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstnamefield" name="fname" placeholder="First Name">
  <span class="help-block" id="firstnamespan" style="display:none">Please enter First Name</span>
</div>
```

Then create your javascript with. (Beware that javascript is case sensitive):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  function validateForm(){

    var firstname = document.getElementById('firstnamefield').value;
    if(firstname == ''){
      document.getElementById('firstnamediv').className = 'form-group has-error';
      document.getElementById('firstnamespan').style.display = 'block';
      return false;
    }
    else if(firstname != ''){
      document.getElementById('firstnamediv'.className = ''form-group has-success';
      document.getElementById('firstnamespan').style.display = 'none';
    }

  }
</script>
```

Then, to call the javascript function we have created, we must set an `onsubmit` attribute on your `<form>`

```
<form method="POST" action="create.php" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
```

Comment: still the same i just want to trigger that "form-group has-error" and the "help-block" i tried to modify the code but still the same btw these are the codes if you would like to check https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B76wr1kvOEudck42X1ZTODVMbjg/view?usp=sharing thanks

Comment: got it fixed man so the required attribute overrides the condition i just removed required="required" thanks for the help i appreciate it :)